# Cascading z-index with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, z-index

So I have a list like so;

```
<ul>
  <li>Sausage</li>
  <li>Egg</li>
  <li>Parsnip</li>
  <li>Sarsaparilla</li>
  <li>Burger</li>
  <li>Cilantro</li>
</ul>
```

I'd need to add a "cascading `z-index`" dynamically to a specific li, so that I could specify a `li` to be the top one and all other `li`s to be decreasingly behind it.

For example, if I had a jQuery `click()` event bound to a function that would dynamically calculate the `z-index`es the way I want, and I clicked "Parsnip", the list would now look like so;

```
<ul>
  <li style="z-index: 2;">Sausage</li>
  <li style="z-index: 3;">Egg</li>
  <li style="z-index: 4;">Parsnip</li>
  <li style="z-index: 3;">Sarsaparilla</li>
  <li style="z-index: 2;">Burger</li>
  <li style="z-index: 1;">Cilantro</li>
</ul>
```

Clicking "Cilantro" would make the list look like this;

```
<ul>
  <li style="z-index: 1;">Sausage</li>
  <li style="z-index: 2;">Egg</li>
  <li style="z-index: 3;">Parsnip</li>
  <li style="z-index: 4;">Sarsaparilla</li>
  <li style="z-index: 5;">Burger</li>
  <li style="z-index: 6;">Cilantro</li>
</ul>
```

In other words, the clicked `li` would have the highest `z-index` necessary to bring to front (would need to be calculated, as the number of `li`s can be anything), its immediate siblings would have one lower, their siblings one lower yet, etc. etc.

How would I possibly achieve this? The list items don't necessarily need to be assigned the exact same `z-index` numbers as illustrated, as long as the visual effect of 'cascading' elements with the clicked being the highest is achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var prev = $(this).prevAll();
    var next = $(this).nextAll();
    var count = prev.length;
    if (next.length > count){
        count = next.length;
    }
    $(this).css({zIndex: count+1});
    prev.each(setIndex);
    next.each(setIndex);
    function setIndex(i){
        $(this).css({zIndex: count-i})
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UaaNn/

Comment: Way more elegant than my solution. I wasn't sure `prevAll()` returned the elements in order to the closest sibling (but it does: "the elements are returned in order beginning with the closest sibling."). Take this one, OP.